# Compile LaTeX multi-source project to Markdown

Tags: luatex, standalone, pandoc, conversion, markdown

I am writing a quite complex LaTeX project, involving:

- user-defined environments/commands
- LuaLaTeX-specific dependencies
- TiKZ figures
- multiple source files handled with the `import` and `standalone` packages
- bibliography

Besides the compilation to pdf, I would like to compile my document into a markdown version for online publishing.

I have been looking into [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) to accomplish this but I just get a blank output in the resulting markdown file when I launch the program on the main file. Conversely, it works fine when launched on the individual chapters files. E.g.

```
pandoc -s -o main.md main.tex
```

produces a blank `.md` file, while

```
pandoc -s chapter01.md chapter01.tex
```

produces the expected result.

My best assumption is that pandoc is not able to parse projects that use `import` and `standalone`, as it works fine with projects using the built-in `\input{}` syntax.

I have been looking into the pandoc docs but no use case with a setup similar to mine is reported. Is there a way to make pandoc work with `import` and `standalone`? If not, is there a way to produce a markdown document out of my LaTeX source, without having to manually reformat the whole codebase?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you want tikz to be in markdown, images?  also translating your "luatex dependencies" will depend on what they are, markdown has no Lua so if you have `\directlua{...}` in your document translating that to anything will depend  on the details of the Lua code

Comment: why do you want to convert your document markdown for web publishing when you can just convert it to HTML easily?